# PHP MySQL: How to tackle maximum users connection exceed limit

Tags: php, mysql

I hope everyone of you are well, staying safe and healthy.

I am working on a professional website. Basically, its a dynamic website where users logged in daily and find some tasks and do them and then upload their proof and then get their rewards.

Now, the website reached to a number of daily users that I am receiving an error related to maximum users exceed limit.

I am using PHP (Core) & MySQL. I am using a VPS Server for the website, also the hosting providers are saying that I am not using the full resources but I don't know why I am receiving this error.

I'm confused that when ever I execute some query, I build connect with DB & then execute the query and after that closed the connection. But still I am receiving this error.

Overview related to Coding style that I am using ....

I am connecting with the DB using the below code.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user1","pass1","my_db");
```

I am executing the query using the below link.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('$name')";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

I am closing the DB connection after executing the query using the below code.

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

The above is just an overview of the coding style that I am using. I am using all the required functions to overcome injections etc. Or try & catch to catch the errors too.

What is the reason that I am getting maximum connections exceed error.

I have lots of users that are coming to websites & the queries are so simple not complex.

Please help.

Comment: well... obviously you run into that issue as you handle opening and closing the connection for every query. The more users try to enter values at the same time, the more problems you will see. Either memorize the connection or decouple (eg. storing values in files and cron-jobbing them into the DB by one job) inserts from the user interaction

Comment: If i don't close the connection then if 1000 of users logged in at the same time then ? Also the queries are like that they can't be cache or can add as cron. So what to do in this case then ?

Comment: Connections are closed automatically when the script ends. What your server's limit? Are we talking about 10 or 1000?

Comment: Why could you not cache the query values and run it later? Looks like a trivial insert. But yeah, just use one connection object for the whole lifetime of your script, don't keep re-opening it. That should help a lot, before you consider anything more drastic

Comment: So, can anyone tell me the possible flow how to connect with DB and execute query and when to close to close the connection.

Comment: The only important thing to take into account is to reuse the same connection during script execution. Opening MySQL connections is cheap but not free. But we can't say there's a workflow problem until we compare the website traffic with the DB limits.

Comment: Actually, e.g login.php page is used to authenticate the user and then redirect the user to fetch tasks page to fetch the task., each time when user navigate to some page then it means we have to build the connection again as refreshing the page means closing the connection or connection variable. So i have to connect with DB each time when usser refreshes.

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/php/example/9383/close-connection

Comment: Check the above link.

Comment: Yes you can connect each time the user refreshes, that's normal. But connecting again each time you run a separate query within one script is not necessary. It's now not clear if that is happening anywhere or not. I don't think we've been given a [mre] of the issue. Also you still didn't mention what the max number of connections actually is, or how many concurrent users your application is experiencing at busy times.

Comment: if connect each time is normal thing then still i am getting connection limit error. the amount of users my website is more than 1k at a time too. also max connections limit is 500 yet and i increase it to 1k. but the issue came again and again.

Comment: Obviously we don't know the overall capacity of your webserver and database server in terms of hardware or other limitations but maybe you need to consider upgrading your platform. Its difficult to be sure...we don't have much information

Comment: "the amount of users my website is more than 1k at a time too" — Most of the time spent in a web application is used to read or type and doesn't typically trigger new HTTP connections. Having 1k concurrent requests means you have a much higher total of visitors browsing the site. If you mean 1k concurrent users rather than requests, you may not even have more than a dozen simultaneous DB sessions. I suspect you don't want to check DB parameters and status because that isn't your area, but it's difficult to optimise if you don't have any metric.